# PHP Logs in native console Firefox Developer

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I highly prefer the firefox developer inspector than the firebug one.

But is that possible to display PHP logs in the native JS console ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Firefox Developer Tools runs on the client-side browser code. PHP runs on the server side and produces HTML for the browser to render. So, this is not possible.

Comment: This can be done using FirePHP and the FireBug Console, so your explanation of why it is not possible is not really true ?

Comment: I thought FirePHP sent logs to the browser, which is generally only a good idea in development environment. In a development environment you can keep the local log file open.

Comment: firephp sends logs(info/warning/error/…) via http headers. but there is no module to handle this in native console (firebug is required :/ )

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Chrome Logger ( [github](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromelogger) | [website](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) ) with [Chrome PHP](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp) to accomplish this in Chrome since Firefox 50+ broke FirePHP.  I then learned that Firefox's web console has been supporting Chrome Logger since v43 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Server).

So in short, yes, you can log PHP variables to the Firefox web console using Chrome PHP.  It's this simple:

1. Download the latest Chrome PHP library:
   https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp
2. Include it in your project (`include 'ChromePhp.php';`)
3. Log something in your php script (`ChromePhp::log($_MyArray);`)
4. Open Firefox web console and turn on the **Server** tab (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Filtering_by_category)

Hope this helps.  I procrastinated upgrading Firefox for a few years before discovering that newer versions had support for this.